# Is there a ifx-elsex statement in Verilog/SV like casex?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Say I have a scenario in which I need to compare only a few bits of a register and I don't care about other bits. eq, I need to check the first and last bits of a 3 bit register (A[2:0]) and I don't care about the middle bit, say compare vector is 3'b1X0 (Parameter).

1. Simplest way to do this is choose all the bits I care about, AND them and I have generated a control signal:
   `if ((A[2]==1) & ((A[0]==0))` Here the condition inside `if` statement is my control signal.
2. Another way is to use a casex statement: `casex(A) begin 3'b1?0: ... , ... endcase`.
3. Is there anything like ifx-elsex statement or something that can be used to do this kind of operation without using the 1st and 2nd method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if (A[2:0] inside {3'b1?0} )`

SystemVerilog keyword `inside`. It has been supported since at least Accellera's SystemVerilog 3.1 (before SystemVerilog was a part of IEEE). [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) 11.4.13 has examples of use. `inside` is synthesizable.

There is also `if ( A[2:0] ==? 3'b1?0 )` ([IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) 11.4.6). The only reference I have on hand (a book published 2004) says it is not supported for synthesis yet. You are welcome to try it.

Comment: Thanks! According to a reference book I am using `if ( A[2:0] ==? 3'b1?0 )` is synthesizable, but `if ( A[2:0] ==? B )` where `B` is some register is not. So only thing to take care is that while using `==?` RHS should be a constant for synthesis.

Answer (score 2):

`(A[2]==1)` is a logical expression the `&` is a bitwise operator, although either works it would be better semantics to use the `&&` logical and operator. This is slightly different to most other languages where the `&&` is a [short-circuit operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Logically what you want is `if ((A[2]==1) && ((A[0]==0))` but it could be reduced to a bitwise expression :

```
if ( ~A[0] & A[2] )
```

NB: Try to avoid using casex, the unknown parts will match x's in simulation. Try to use `casez` instead, ? can still be used to match don't cares.

**Update comparing inside to casez**

Case statements a clean control structure used in most languages to avoid large if elsif else chains. the inside operation will match x's to the do not care '?' values. this makes it usage similar to the casex which is considered to be bad practise to use as it can hide simulation fails.

```
casez(sel)
  4'b1??? a= 3'd4;
  4'b01?? a= 3'd3;
  4'b001? a= 3'd2;
  4'b0001 a= 3'd1;
  4'b0000 a= 3'd0;  
endcase
```

vs

```
if (sel inside {4'b1???})
  a= 3'd4;
else if (sel inside {4'b01??})
  a= 3'd3;
else if (sel inside {4'b001?})
  a= 3'd2;
...
```

The above is actually equal to the casex (but more verbose) I believe that instead of casex you could also use :

```
case(sel) inside
  4'b1??? a= 3'd4;
  4'b01?? a= 3'd3;
  4'b001? a= 3'd2;
  4'b0001 a= 3'd1;
  4'b0000 a= 3'd0;  
endcase
```

but then I would never use a casex.

Comment: In system Verilog I think using `inside` in a `case` would be the best way to do some don't care operations. I wouldn't be surprised if casex and casez operators wouldn't ever have to be used, what are your thoughts?

Comment: Just the other day I was using some features of SystemVerilog to cleanup some code, Simulated great, Synthesised with some warnings. Updated code to remove the warnings. Simulating great runs through synthesis clean. Generated netlist was invalid. **If you decide to use a new SystemVerilog construct check that it can clear your entire workflow, not just simulation**

Comment: Although I often do post Place and Route netlist simulation, so it automatically takes care of the synthesized netlist. Will make it a point to always do the simulations in case of using System Verilog especially while using new constructs. Thanks!

Comment: Minor point on short-circuit operators - `&&` and `||` have been short-circuit since at least the '95 LRM; I think this might have been unspecified in previous OVI/Cadence docs.

Comment: @EML had not realised that they were actually short-circuit, but in most languages you get to choose short-circuit or not, here we choose bitwise or logical. Short-circuit is side effect free unless used with `i++` or similar in secondary or later logic expression. Which was fine because we did not have them until now ...

Comment: @Ujjwal I have updated answer with my views on inside vs casex, hope it helps.

Comment: @Morgan One more point of difference that you may want to edit your answer with is that of a priority encoding nature of if-else statements versus case statement. In your if-else example, `sel inside {4'b00??}` comes after `sel inside {4'b0???}` so it will never be executed.

Comment: @Ujjwal well spotted, missed the 1's out of the encoder. A updated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no operator I'm aware of that allows you to use '?' or 'x' inside an equality comparison to have them ignored.

Another alternative that you didn't mention would be to use a bitmask to select the bits you only care about. If you have a lot of bits this can be more compact than testing each bit individually.

If you only care about `A == 3'b1?0`, then it can be written as such:

`if((A & 3'b101) == 3'b100)`

Comment: Yes, this also a nice alternative method. While using Verilog, I think this would be the best way to use `if` statement for don't care bit operations. Thanks!